# ExtJS4.0 limits 5000 record while reading the store in controller

Tags: extjs

I have grid with 10000 records. I am trying to retrive the grid data by reading the store which populates the grid. But I am not able to read all the data from the store. In stead only 5000 record are being retrieved. Is there a limit ExtJs4? Please find below the code snippet.

enter code here

```
    onDownloadXLS : function(btn, e) {
        var store = this.getGridStoreStore();
        alert(store.getCount());// This is returning only 5000 rows not 10000.
        var records = store.data.items.map(function(r){ return r.data });
    }

    Ext.define('MyApp.store.GridStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.GridModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: "data/test.json",
        reader: {
            type: 'json', 
            root: 'performance'
        }
    },
    sorters: {property: 'uploadedDate', direction: 'DESC'},
    groupField: 'uploadedDate',
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Comment: @Sashikant.....Can you post your store config?

Comment: @Sashikant......`pageSize: 500` will load 500 rows into store.

Comment: Ext.define('MyApp.store.GridStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.GridModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: "data/test.json",
        reader: {
            type: 'json', 
            root: 'performance'
        }
    },
    sorters: {property: 'uploadedDate', direction: 'DESC'},
    groupField: 'uploadedDate',
    autoLoad: true
});

Comment: Even with no pageSize it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

The only answer I can give you here is that a browser application should never load that amount of data. You have a design issue if you are forced loading that much data.

You should either use paging or infinite scrolling (with a buffered store) in case of a grid and delegate all sort and search/filter operations to the server.

Basically there is no limitation. See this **[Sencha example of infinite scrolling](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/infinite-scroll.html)** with over 6000 records.

Comment: The purpose of reading these many data is to send all the data to server(in JSON form) and do some processing. It is important that at the server end all the data in the store is available. In the UI grid we may show less amount od data.